# Filling an array of struct from a file with fscanf while checking new line (feedback)

Tags: c, file, struct, scanf, fgetc

I have a .txt file where every line is like:

```
id name surname 78 99 101 12 33 44
```

Every line I need to fill a struct of `Student`. The numbers after `surname` have to be stored in an array of structs `Lesson`. The first number (for example `78`) is a struct field and the second number (`99`) is another struct field. The pairs after surname can be a maximum of 8. I'm a bit confused since I don't know how many pairs there will be and I found this method but am not sure the way I check newline (\n) is good.

```
typedef struct Lesson
{
    int hour;
    int time;
}Lesson;

typedef struct Student
{
    int id;
    char name_and_surname[100];
    Lesson lessons[8];
    struct Student *next;
}Student;
```

```
Student s;

while (fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s", &s.id, s.name_and_surname, tmp) == 3)
{
    int i = 0;
    strcat(s.name_and_surname, " ");
    strcat(s.name_and_surname, tmp);
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp) != '\n') && fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &s.lessons[i].hour, &s.lessons[i].time) == 2) 
      {
            i++;
      }
       
       //add s to a linked list
}
```

Comment: If the lines have variable format (such as the differing number of fields you describe) then `fscanf` is a poor choice for parsing them.  More often than not, reading a line at a time via `fgets` and parsing the resulting string is a more robust alternative.

Comment: Can *name* and *surname* contain space or digit? Is it you who designed the file format or is this imposed by your teacher?

Comment: @fpiette By my teacher. Its not specified about name_and_surname. I imagine this would be a problem if I parse a string from fgets containing all the line like other suggested.

Comment: Is `fscanf` also a requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, if your input is organized as one record per line with variable-format lines then it is probably best to read it a whole line at a time, maybe with `fgets()`, and then to parse the result into its fields.  There are numerous alternatives for the parsing, among them `sscanf()`, `strtok()`, and `strtol()`.

If you *must* do the job by directly scanning each field via `fscanf()` then this is possible, but messy.  The particular approach you present is not robust: it will not recognize newlines on lines with trailing spaces, and it will not recognize lines that are malformed by having an odd number of trailing numbers.

You could, for example, use something like this instead:

```
/*
 * Scan one int from file 'fp' into the location pointed to by 'dest',
 * skipping any leading whitespace other than newlines.
 *
 * Returns:
 *  1   on success
 *  0   if a non-numeric field is found before the next newline
 *  EOF if end of file or end of line is reached without encountering
 *      an input field, or on error
 */
int scan_one_number(FILE *fp, int *dest) {

    // skip leading whitespace, but stop at a newline
    while (1) {
        int c = fgetc(fp);
        
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n') {
            // terminate on error, end-of-file, or end-of-line
            return EOF;
        } else if (!isspace(c)) {
            // a non-whitespace character

            // push it back onto the stream
            if (ungetc(c, fp) != c) {
                // error
                return EOF;
            }

            // break out of the loop
            break;
        } // else it's non-newline whitespace; ignore it
    }

    // attempt to scan a decimal integer
    return fscanf(fp, "%d", dest);
}
```

That would allow you to scan one number at a time with `scanf`, recognizing end-of-line and malformed inputs.

Comment: That is **not** an answer to the question!

Comment: What question, @fpiette?  The closest thing there is to a question is "*I don't know how many pairs there will be and I found this method but am not sure the way I check newline (\n) is good*."  This answer responds directly to that, starting in the second paragraph, offering criticism of the OP's proposed approach and a basis for an alternative that would not be subject to the same criticisms.  Plus, the OP seems to be satisfied.

Comment: I mean the title: "Filling an array of struct from a file".

Comment: @fpiette, the title does not express a question, and the text that goes with it does not support interpreting the title as more than presenting a general context for the post.  By all means, however, feel free to write your own answer if you have one that you think would be more responsive to what the OP wants to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's ok only if you know that the input of Lesson must be in pairs and it wont be odd.
in this case you can fill the end of the array lessons with 0 or null or even -1 or so. You do it because you probably want to print it afterward.
something like that:

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    s.lessons[j].hour = 0;
    s.lessons[j].time = 0;
}
```